# Can exceptions automatically provide details about their environment?

Tags: c++, exception

What I would like to do:

```
struct A
{
    void f()
    {
        throw auto_exception("something went wrong");
    }
}

class Foo
{
    void bar()
    {
        throw auto_exception("step 2 failed");
    }
}
```

The exception's `what()` string should read, respectively:

```
"Exception in A::f(). something went wrong"
"Exception in Foo::bar(). step 2 failed"
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presuming that your C++ compiler supports `__FUNCTION__` (or `__func__` in C++11) you can define AUTO_EXCEPTION as:

```
#define AUTO_EXCEPTION( msg ) std::runtime_error( std::string(__FUNCTION__) + ": " + msg )
```

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't really call what you want "information about the environment". You might be able to piece that together with the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` macros as well as with `__func__` (or maybe `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` in GCC, or check your compiler's manual for other suitable extensions).

What might be a lot more interesting is the *dynamic* environment, such as an execution trace of the point where you raise the exception. You can produce those at runtime with a library like [libunwind](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/). It's quite expensive to produce the trace, but since you're only doing it in the event of an exception, that should be fine.